# CKAN open data sort newest entries dataset

Tags: ckan

I want to show newest CKAN dataset on homepage of CKAN. Right now, it is showed, but it is not sorted. I want to the dataset sorted with newest like on dataset page.

Comment: Pls mention what you have done so far.

Comment: i have copied this code from search.html in package folder : {% block package_search_results_list %}
        {{ h.snippet('snippets/package_list.html', packages=c.page.items) }}
      {% endblock %}


And change it to : {% block package_search_results_list %}
        {% snippet 'snippets/package_list.html', packages=c.datasets %}
      {% endblock %}